# Development setup on linux

Tags: linux, java, development, hadoop

On a linux system should we install and use our development tools and setup like java ee and hadoop as a root user or as user.

Comment: Might I suggest against developing on Linux at this time if you need to ask this question? I spend all day dealing with the product of (probably) similar developers and it causes at best frustration and at worst a vulnerable system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't run it as root, that's a serious security risk. Setup a new user for each if needed and make sure that they only have access to what they strictly need. If your application doesn't run without root privileges it might be a good idea to think about rewriting the parts needing it

Comment: It also helps if the installer does not require root to run,  Extract anything needing root into a script that can be run by the system admin.